# How to call Method (Object o)in the same Class in Hashtable

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, hashtable

I'm confused how to call a Method that returned a Key in the same class, acctualy I want to implementing a Hashtable. So a Hashtable that save the key  from Method`hashrealCode(Employee e)` using Java.Lang.Object. it's that impossible ?

**for my Object class**

```
public class Employee {   // I created this class to prepare the Object
int id;
String name;
    public Empployee(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int hashCode() {
    final int Number = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = Number * result + id;
    result = Number * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

public int id() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int Id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

 }
```

**and in this class I want to add the key to my Hashtable (Array)**

```
public class HashTableEmployee {
Employee[] array;

public void addTheEmployee(Employee e){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
            array[i] =  hashrealCode(Employee e) //??? I just want to save the key form Method-hashrealCode(Employee e) to my array, but it didnt work 
        }
}

public Employee[] getArray(){
    return array;
}

public void setArray(Employee[] array){
    this.array = array;
}


public int hashrealCode(Employee e){  //create my own key
    int hash_value = Math.abs(e.hashCode()) % array.length;
    return hash_value;  //I want to save this hashCode in my array 
}


public Employee(int capacity){  // for the length of Array
    array = new Employee[capacity];
}

   }
```

So how I cant save the key (Method-hashrealCode) in to my array that i created i a method ? when I tried to call the method, it didn't work

Comment: Are you trying to do `array[i] =  hashrealCode(e);`? (Method calls don't repeat the type declarations needed in method declarations) - And if you want to store an `int` in `array` it needs to be `int[] array;` and I also doubt you want to store the value in a loop in every slot of that array..

Comment: thats why I searching the solution. how to call the the method `hashrealCode(e)`

Comment: but in this case I'm using `Java.Lang.Object` so I need to declare the are `Employee [] array`. I can't use `int`. yes, I want to store the value (key)  in every slot of that `Employee [] array`

Comment: With hashtables, you use the hash to determine the position in the array, something along the lines of `int index = hashrealCode(e); array[index] = e;` or `array[hashrealCode(e)] = e;` in one line.

Comment: it didn't work too hahaha @zapl

Comment: Because of the `for` loop in `addTheEmployee` method you will put the same `Employee` object to every element on your `array`. Also you do not check for hash collisions when hash code has the same value for different objects

Comment: so how I do in `addTheEmployee` that ? like this  :  ` for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {array[i] = hashrealCode(array[i]);}`

Comment: `public void addTheEmployee(Employee e){
            array[hashrealCode(e)] =  e;
}`

Comment: what if I set like this: `array[i].id = hashrealCode(e);` so the Hashvalue will be restore in the Id during add the all Employee ?